# How do I move a stacked image to another page after modification?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have a page to let the customer modify the colors of 5 layers of an image.  I am using `getPixels` to change the color based on a palette of 9 color families with about 188 colors per family to choose from.  The image manipulation works great, but I cannot figure out how to get the completed image to the next page, which is the final verification prior to ordering their product.

How can I get this completed image to the next page?

Relevant code (for one layer of the image):

```
    var bg = document.getElementById("layer1");
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");      
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var originalPixels = null;//background
    var currentPixels = null;//background

    function changeColorBlue()
    {
        if(!originalPixels) return; // Check if image has loaded
        var newColor = HexToRGB(document.getElementById("colorbbg").value);

        for(var I = 0, L = originalPixels.data.length; I < L; I += 4)
        {
            if(currentPixels.data[I + 3] > 0)
            {
                currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor.R;
                currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor.G;
                currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor.B;
            }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(currentPixels, 0, 0);
        bg.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    }
```

Comment: canvas.toDataURL("image/png") is your image ... store it somewhere and post it to the next page.

Comment: i've tried to use this:  window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image/png", "width=900, height=600", "canvas_width, canvas_height"); but it only returns the origional image

Comment: yeah ... no... that is wrong.

Comment: i thought so.  i'm still new to this, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the variable for the new window function is : var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

Comment: no... if u store the canvas.toDataUrl() you get the modified image. and you need to post the image if you open a new page/window or you write the whole code for the next page in a var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get this completed image to the next page?

Here is one way you can get your image data around, and that is by using `Web Storage` (supported in all major browser including IE8):

To save the image:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('myImage', canvas.toDataURL());
```

and from any other page after that in the same domain you can retrieve it by:

```
img.src = sessionStorage.getItem('myImage');
```

Works with different tabs as well (as long as it is same origin).

Just be aware of size limitations with Web Storage which can vary from browser to browser (2.5 - 5 mb usually - plus the string takes 2 bytes per char so the data-uri should be less than 1 mb to be safe). If JPEG format is ok you can provide the image as:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('myImage', canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.6));
```

to deal with "safer" sizes.

If you want to permanently store the image you can use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`.

Comment: i think it'll have to stay a png file for what i'm doing.  so i would change image/jpeg to image/png then?

Comment: @KeithYutzy sure, though you don't actually need to specify type if you want to have PNG, as PNG is the default format (in the standard).

Comment: so then i should add the sessionStorage at the end of the code for each layer?  i appreciate you're patience and help.  i am still learning.

Comment: @KeithYutzy you should merge all those layers into one single image (if possible) first, then just store the final merged image. You can merge them by using drawImage to a new canvas for each layer provided they have transparency information.

Comment: thank you for your help and advice.  i'll get to work on merging the images .